# Why is this site breaking in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

This site works fine in IE6 and 7, as well as other browsers but now in IE8. I don't have a copy to test it out myself and am wondering if you guys could help.

http://x.brantonprojects.com/clientloop/LINC/Website/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your overflow autos to `overflow:hidden`. Or use the clearfix and just trigger hasLayout on the float containers.

I would set `zoom:1;` on `#content-wrapper` and `#content-single` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

html {
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
}

!important is still an issue with ie